# Delete cookies from local LAN website

Tags: safari, cookies

How do I delete specific website data from a `.local` LAN website? I can't find it in the view for specific website storage:

[image: Screenshot of Safari's Privacy tab showing 'No Saved Website Data' of a local website]

Using **Remove All** works, but is for developing not a good solution. Is there anything I oversee or a workaround?

Comment: .local is synonymous with .com or .org.  You don’t search for domains like that.  You need to search for the name provided by the http server that created the cookie which might be foo.bar and not foo.local

Comment: Even `raspberrypi` doesn't show anything. The full hostname is `raspberrypi.local`. Tried just searching for the TLD and it works for other websites.

Comment: Not the DNS name, but the *http server* name.  Sometimes, they are both (i.e apple.com). When a cookie is written, it’s based on the name the http server provides.  In other words, you could connect to foo.bar on the network, but the web server’s name is “ilikepointyhats.com”.  And that’s if the cookies are written that way.

Comment: Why not get a cookie inspector/editor plugin for the browser you’re using?  There are many out there that have search functions where you can limit your results to a certain time period.